# Akka List of futures - how to wait for list of futures to finish?

Tags: java, akka

*newbie* here...

I've got a very simple callable on a collection of domain objects.  In using futures, all I care about is truly knowing when all the futures have completed.

So I'm creating a collection of futures, iterating over my domain objects, creating a future (with the callable) and adding it to the collection of futures.

Assuming that the callable returns a Boolean, how can I ascertain that all the futures have been completed.

Oh! I want to wait till this collection is processed before I process another collection as the 2nd collection process is dependent on the 1st.

Any help appreciated.

**SAID DIFFERENTLY**:
How can I wait for all of items of an array to finish?  Do I have to iterate and wait on each?

```
ArrayList<Future<Object>> responses = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();
```

PS: coding in JAVA and also *confused* on use of PartialFunctions etc., on perhaps applying filter, counting and comparing against collection size as a possible solution...

Answer (score 4):

OK - solved it by doing the following:

```
Await.result(seq, Duration.create("5 seconds"));
```

where

```
Future<Iterable<Boolean>> seq = Futures.sequence(futures, ec);
```

and `futures` is the collection of futures i.e., `ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the example from [this article](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/09/21/java-concurrency-with-akka-composing-futures):

```
Future<Iterable<Long>> futuresSequence = sequence(futures);

// block until the futures come back
Iterable<Long> results = futuresSequence.get();
```

It appears that you're attempting to compose futures, but you've nested your collection and futures the wrong way around for this to work correctly.  Try making a `Future` of type `Iterable` instead, and then calling `get` on this future.

Comment: Thanks Gian,
There is no .get() on Futures.sequence in Java under Akka 2.1.2
@ the "wrong way around" - I didn't explain fully. 
It's exactly the same as in the article. When adding the futures, I want to collect them in a ArrayList<Future<xyz>>, and when I call Futures.sequence(), I'll get the Future<Iterable<xyz>>.

Comment: I'm confused.  You're still getting a `Future` back.  Why does waiting for this future not work for your use case?